# Unique random numbers in listbox

Tags: c#, random

I was wondering how can I get 8 unique random numbers in my listbox, code so far:

```
lbLeft.Items.Clear();
Random rnd = new Random();
int n = rnd.Next();
int x = 8;

do
{
    lbL.Items.Add(rnd.Next(0, 20));

} while ((lbLeft.Items.Count != x));
```

It is filling the listbox with 8 random numbers, but I need them unique.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: I'd like to understand difference between `unique` and `random`, not the same? then how about checking for uniqueness every time you are adding item to listbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this check in your code: `if(!lbl.Items.Contains(n))`

```
lbLeft.Items.Clear();
Random rnd = new Random();
int n = rnd.Next();
int x = 8;

do
{
    n = rnd.Next(0, 20);
    if(!lbl.Items.Contains(n))
        lbL.Items.Add(n);

} while ((lbLeft.Items.Count != x));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
HashSet<int> uniques = new HashSet<int>();  
Random random = new Random();  
while(uniques.Count!= 8)  
{
    uniques.Add(random.Next(0,20));  //terrible upper bound
}
```

The `Set` will guarantee that duplicates cannot be contained within it.

Comment: The question is tagged as `C#` and not `Java`, did you mean `HashSet<T>`? Also, you're missing a closing bracket on your add call.

Comment: @DGibbs Sure.  Thankfully 5 other people were able to see the similarities between `Java` and `C#`.  However, to provide the **most** correct answer, what needs to change?

Comment: @Woot4Moo `uniques.add(random.Next(0,20);` should be `uniques.add(random.Next(0,20));` for starters ;)

Comment: @Nolonar ok, updated that one.  Is the declaration supposed to be `HashSet<Integer> uniques = new HashSet<Integer>()`?

Comment: @Woot4Moo Would you like me to correct it for you? If the question is marked as `C#` then the answer should **be** in `C#`, regardless of the similarities between the two languages.

Comment: @DGibbs by all means feel free to correct it.  And yes I understand that the question is marked `C#`

Comment: @Woot4Moo No, it's `HashSet<int> uniques = new HashSet<int>();` you would also need to change `size`, to `Count` and `add` to `Add` for this to be correct.

Comment: @DGibbs and fixed all the way now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list from 0 to n, choose a random from that list, remove it and decrement your max value by one.  This way you know that you will only go through the for look x times.

```
    lbLeft.Items.Clear();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int x = 8;
    int upperBound = 20;
    List<int> uniqueInts = new List<int>(upperBound);
    for (int i = 0; i < upperBound; i++)  
        uniqueInts.Add(i);

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++ )
    {
        int index = rnd.Next(0, uniqueInts.Count);
        lbLeft.Items.Add(uniqueInts[index]);
        uniqueInts.RemoveAt(index);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lbLeft.Items.Clear();
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    n = rnd.Next(0, 20);
    while(lbLeft.Contains(n.ToString())
    {
        n = rnd.Next(0, 20);
    }
    al.Add(n);
    lbL.Items.Add(n.ToString())
}
```